# Ansible run a task based on something in output

Tags: ansible, yaml, wiki, ansible-template

I'm new in Ansible and I try to do some practice playbook. I write a playbook to deploy a Docker container as follows. I write a task in the block section if an error happened, run a task in the rescue section based on Failed message content. For example, I want to run a specific task to delete an existing container if the Failed message is something like this:

> failed: [192.168.1.140] (item=stderr_lines) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["docker", "run", "-itd", "--name", "h1", "-p", "80:80", "httpd"], "delta": "0:00:00.016385", "end": "2021-01-04 03:00:55.403364", "failed_when_result": true, "item": "stderr_lines", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 125, "start": "2021-01-04 03:00:55.386979", "stderr": "/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/h1" is already in use by container bc5cc803a5f4321358992d06097ce271f3a63b8eba19900cfc0d23e321a4e243. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..\nSee '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.", "stderr_lines": ["/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/h1" is already in use by container bc5cc803a5f4321358992d06097ce271f3a63b8eba19900cfc0d23e321a4e243. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..", "See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}"

---

My playbook is as follows but it didn't work correctly. Sometimes an error in reading dictionary or *"Unexpected templating type error occurred on"*. Can somebody guide me on what should I write?

```yaml
- name: run a container
  vars:
   - run_container: docker run -itd --name h1 -p 80:80 httpd
   - rm_container: docker stop h1 && docker rm h1

  hosts: 192.168.x.x
  tasks:
  - name: check docker container
    block:
    - name: run a container httpd
      command: "{{run_container}}"
      register: rss
      with_items:
        - "stderr_lines"
      failed_when: "'Error' in rss.stderr"

    rescue:
     - name: iterate over list
       debug:
         msg: "{{item.value}}"
       loop: "{{rss | dict2items}}"

     - name: remove the exited container
       command: "{{rm_container}}"
       register: rs
       with_items:
        - "{{rss | dict2items}}"
       when: item.value is search("The container name .* is already in use")
```

Comment: learn [yaml](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_basics.htm).

Comment: Do you want the [`docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-container-module) instead?  That will know to not start the container if it's already running.

Comment: Thank you David, I didn't know about that.